# How to find source of leaked threadPools in application

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, java-8

I have several leaked ThreadPools in our application. These leaked threadPools do not have any specific name and use java's default naming convention. All ThreadPools launched by our application have application specific names. It looks some dependency library is launching these threadPools. I was able to reproduce this but need help on how can I find out code that launched these threadPools. Any help is much appreciated.
Stack dump of leaked ThreadPool from application stackDump. All threads are in same state.

```
"pool-11-thread-1" #23 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f9f0c179000 nid=0x12db 
 waiting on condition [0x00007f9f2effa000]
 java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) - parking to wait for <0x000000008858c608>
 (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215) 
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1093)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Locked ownable synchronizers: - None
```

Comment: That's a typical stack dump of an idle threadpool (waiting on tasks to appear in the queue) and unfortunately not very helpful here. A Heap dump and some memory-leak analysis tool (like [this](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)?) could possibly show you which code owns / has references to the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` in question. I don't know of an easy way to find the information

Comment: What do you mean "leaked thread pools"? What is the more immediate issue that you're experiencing? Idle java threads like this one don't really consume any computing resources; at worst, the Thread object itself will consume a few bytes of memory.

Comment: Number of thread pools goes to 32K over a 3 day period causing OS issues. None my code creates these many threads so I am suspecting some dependency. I will try heap dump approach.

Comment: Using heapDump and MAT tool helped me to find objects holding reference to ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. I was able to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the thread log you can see that the thread of this thread pool is 0, need to wait;

In general, the thread pool is best to use a custom name, or bad positioning code block; the above situation can only be combined with the actual operation from the code analysis:

1. List all the thread pools in the code
2. Combine the actual operation of the analysis of which thread pool there are a lot of thread calls

Answer (score 0):

Take the thread dump using jstack command or other tools.
Use TDA (Thread Dump Analyzer) to check waiting thread is waiting on which monitor holding by which thread and why.